# CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is empty for target "cmTC_28d80"

Tags: cmake, cuda, clion, jetbrains-ide

I made a new CUDA executable project in CLion and when it opened I got CMake error:

```
CUDA_ARCHITECTURES is empty for target "cmTC_908f4".
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(test main.cu)

set_target_properties(
        test
        PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

I tried searching for this error on internet but not much success. I only tried to set

```
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "35;50;72")
```

but that didn't help.
At this point I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: @talonmies Tried that, still same error

Comment: I would avoid using `test` as a target name. This name is almost as reserved one by CMake. For the target you could use `test_cuda`, `my_test` or even `test1`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that didn't help either :/

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, and the answer below doesn't fix it. The logs show that the correct compiler is found even without setting that cmake property

Answer (score 3):

Although I am 9 months late to this, I think I actually solved it. I just stumbled across (what I believe to be) exactly the same problem. It occurred while trying to set up a new CUDA Project in CLion, and I got the same error.

I have now contacted the JetBrains support for CLion, and they pointed me to the solution of this problem.

If you have the same problem, you should see an auto-detected "x86" architecture under "Settings/Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Toolchains > [the toolchain you are using for this project]". Simply manually select "amd64" instead (or, I suppose, whatever arch your system is running on), and then the CMake build should run fine, and a simple Hello World should also compile and run without problems.

Version Data:

- CLion 2021.3.4
- CMake 3.21.1 (bundled with CLion)
- CUDA Toolkit 11.6
- MSVC 2022 / Version 17.0
- Windows 11 Pro

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the `Policy CMP0104 is not set: CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES now detected for NVCC` warning, you can [find your SM number/Compute Capability on your GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) (e.g., 3090 Ti is 86) and include it like this:

```bash
cmake .. -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=86 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the order matters, e.g. set Cuda architecture before compile features.  My CMakeLists that works (and didn't before adding the CUDA_ARCHITECTURE line) is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(myTarget LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

# Locate sources and headers for this project
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include /usr/local/cuda/include )

file(GLOB sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc)
file(GLOB headers ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h)
file(GLOB cuda_sources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cu)

# Add the executable, and link 
add_executable(myTarget ${sources} ${cuda_sources} ${headers})
target_link_libraries(myTarget pthread z)

# Compile Info
set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "35;50;72")
target_compile_features(myTarget PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_features(myTarget PUBLIC cuda_std_11)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cuda-projects.html#set-nvcc - add your nvcc path in settings for CMake.
Remember to put full path to executable - not only bin folder

Comment: Please summarize the relevant contents of the page you link to.

Answer (score -1):

I got similar problem and was wondering what actually that `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` stands for. It seems that it stands for particular architecture of NVidia cards for which the program shall be optimized or minimum architecture on which it shall run at all. I have found this [link](https://arnon.dk/matching-sm-architectures-arch-and-gencode-for-various-nvidia-cards/) how these architecture numbers relate to the GPU used.

To cite most important codes:

Turing - CUDA 10+ - 75 [CMAKE default](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html#variable:CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES)

Ampere - CUDA 11.1+ - 80,86,87

Lovelace - CUDA 11.8+ - 89

Hopper - CUDA 12+ - 90

It seems that CMake at some point realized that 75 might be soon outdated but does not want to update it constantly. Thus you shall set it by your own or it warns you and as of now puts 75 as default.

If you will search NVidia, they tend to name these architectures e.g. "compute_50". Because architecture 35 is deprecated in CUDA11 it is not wise to follow CMake example to set
`set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "35;50;72")`
but use rather
`set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "75")` to silence the warning and retain the behavior.